# fullCalendar height not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

So, I'm integrating FullCalendar into my website, and it's working fine other than it won't become any taller than 321px, even with the height option set to much larger numbers. That, however, is irrelevant as the width of the containing element is such that the default settings should render it as taller.

I'm using basic Bootstrap 3, with the media queries reset to be larger than normal - but that would impact width, not height, and it's rendering full width of the parent panel. I've checked my CSS for any errors or conflicts, but none seem to exist. I don't even know where to begin with posting code, as I've not made any modifications.

Help? Anywhere else I should look?

Here's the custom javascript parts for the site:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// $('#calendarThumb').DataTable();

// $('#eventCalendar').DataTable( {paging: false, ordering: false, info: false, lengthChange: false, searching: false });

$("#eventCal").fullCalendar({
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxxx',
    eventSources: [
        {
            googleCalendarId: 'xxxx@group.calendar.google.com'
        },
        {
            googleCalendarId: 'xxxx@group.calendar.google.com'
        }   
    ]
}); 

$("#thumbCal").fullCalendar({
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxxx',
    eventSources: [
        {
            googleCalendarId: 'xxxx@group.calendar.google.com'
        },
        {
            googleCalendarId: 'xxxx@group.calendar.google.com'
        }
    ]   
});


$(".list-group-item").click(function(event) {
    $(".list-group-collapse").collapse('hide');
});

var table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {ordering: true, paging: true });
var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table );

$( tt.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');

$(function () { $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });

$('#imgModal').modal({'backdrop': true});

});

$('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 7000
    }); 



function modalPop(id) {
var src = $(id).attr('src');
var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive"/>';
$('#imgModal').modal();
$('#imgModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#imgModal .modal-body').html(img);
});

$('#imgModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#imgModal .modal-body').html('');
});
};


$('.modalLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');

});

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

    $(this).find('.modal-dialog').css({
              width:'85%x', //choose your width
              height:'98%', 
              'padding':'0'
       });
     $(this).find('.modal-content').css({
              height:'100%', 
              'border-radius':'0',
              'padding':'0'
       });
     $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
              width:'auto',
              height:'100%', 
              'padding':'0'
       });
})
```

And the page code:

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.testsite.com/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.testsite.com/couch/addons/data-bound-form/datetime.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.testsite.com/resources/css/lavish-css.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.testsite.com/resources/css/calendar.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.testsite.com/resources/css/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.css">
    <link href="http://www.testsite.com/resources/css/icon-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.testsite.com/resources/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.testsite.com/resources/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.testsite.com/events_rss.php" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Upcoming Events at GCHRL">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        <!--[if IE]
        .navbar-nav > li {
                    float: left;
                }

        navbar-form .input-group-btn,
        .navbar-form .input-group-addon {
                    width: auto;
                }
        <![endif]-->        
    </style>
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 64px;

        }


        footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

            div.c-wrapper{
                width: 95%; /* for example */
                height: 500px;
                margin: auto;
        }

            .carousel-inner > .item > img, 
            .carousel-inner > .item > a > img{
                margin: auto;
        }

        .row-centered {
            text-align:center;
        }

        .col-centered {
            display:inline-block;
            float:none;
            /* reset the text-align */
            text-align:left;
            /* inline-block space fix */
            margin-right:-4px;
        }

        .navbar > .n-wrapper {
            width: 98%;
        }

        .carousel_item {
            height: 500px;
            width: 800px;
        }   

        html {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            /* Margin bottom by footer height */
            margin-bottom: 60px;
        }
        .footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

        .modal-dialog {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            left-margin: -300px;
        }


    </style>    


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <cms:embed 'menu.html' />
        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <cms:if k_is_page || k_is_archive || k_is_folder>
                    <cms:embed 'cal_archive.html' />
                <cms:else />
                    <div id="eventCal" ></div>
                </cms:if>
            </div>
            <div class='panel-footer'>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.testsite.com/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.testsite.com/resources/js/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.testsite.com/resources/js/jquery.smartmenus.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.testsite.com/resources/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.testsite.com/resources/fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.testsite.com/resources/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.testsite.com/resources/fullcalendar/gcal.js" ></script>
                <script src="http://www.testsite.com/resources/js/custom.js"></script>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>  

</body>
```

Comment: You need to add the relevant code that you're having a problem with in your question, and mock up the problem on JS Fiddle or Bootply if possible.

Comment: I added the relevant code. I'll try to do a fiddle up sometime over the weekend and see if the problem is emulated there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed the fullcalendar.print.css which is causing this error.
This is because you did not set a 'target' for this stylesheet.

You should add 'media="print"' to the link-tag. This will make sure this stylesheet is only used when printing the calendar.

Comment: Thanks! Needing a media tag never occurred to me. - S.

Answer (score 3):

I'll do some looking into the "why," but the basic answer is this: the fullcalendar.print.css interferes with the standard display scaling vertically. If the print css is removed the calendar displays properly.